# Different Type instantiation at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, instantiation, factory-pattern

I have to solve the problem where i need different calculation for each sensor type(I need to decide which type to instantiate at run time). 
Let me show you in an example:

**1. From database table i get this result:**

```
SensorType RawValue ADCGain R0Value I0Value ABCValue 
1          100      0.1     NULL    NULL    NULL
1          150      0.2     NULL    NULL    NULL
2          30       NULL    1       2       2
2          15       NULL    5       5       6
```

Let say sensor type 1 is concrete type **AISensor** and inhertis from base class and type 2 is **Pt100Tempsensor** and inhertis from the same base class.
Here is the class definiton in C#:

```
 public abstract class Sensor
     {
        public abstract int Id { get;  set; }
        public abstract string Code { get;  set; }
        public abstract string Name { get;  set; }

        public abstract double GetCalculatedValue(int rawValue);
    }

   public class Pt100Tempsensor : Sensor
    {

        public int R0Value { get; set; }
        public int I0value { get; set; }
        public int ABCValue { get; set; }
        public override int Id { get; set; }
        public override string Code { get; set; }
        public override string Name { get; set; }

        public override double GetCalculatedValue(int rawValue)
        {
            return ((R0Value * I0value) / ABCValue) * rawValue;
        }
    }

public class AISensor : Sensor
{
    public int AdcGain { get; set; }
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public override string Code { get; set; }
    public override string Name { get; set; }

    public override double GetCalculatedValue(int rawValue)
    {
        return rawValue * AdcGain;
    }
}
```

Now i am wondering what is the best way to instantiate objects at run time to achieve that if i add new sensor type, i don't need to change an existing code(like in simple factory method "pattern").

Thank's for any help.

Comment: Yes, use a simple factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use factory that creates concrete sensors based on sensor type ID

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is a factory method with a switch based on the ID that makes a different sensor depending on the ID number.

If you want to be able to add sensors without changing any other code (i.e. without altering the factory method) then you need to use reflection to (1) discover all available sensor types and (2) construct the right one based on its ID. You could so this with an attribute eg:

```
[Sensor(42)]
public class Pt100Tempsensor : Sensor
{
    ....
```

Where 42 is the ID

But to be honest, it's only worth the effort of doing this if you are going to really have loads of sensor types.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion for a simple factory pattern.

But: If you really need to add new sensors **without touching existing code**, I can only think of a "plugin system". That means:

- You have a common interface.
- You have some sort of configuration where you can map IDs to Implementations.
- You have a Factory that can detect implementations and create instances based on above mentioned configuration.

For reference: Microsoft has a little example code. See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62

Comment: If i use autofac then actually don't realy need to use simple factory pattern at all right?I would register type in ioc container like this: ioc.RegisterType<Sensor, AISensor>("1");, ioc.RegisterType<Sensor, Pt100Tempsensor >("2");

Comment: I am not (yet) familiar with autofac in particular. I guess there should be a way to achieve that behavior with DI. Only problem is: you still need to register implementations with the DI framework somehow. I'll update the answer, as soon as I can get some info on that.

Comment: Ok thanks...Yes but still you have to just update ioc type mapping class/config file...

Comment: Have a look at this: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mef.html Not sure if it is what you are looking for. Sounds like it, though on first sight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ORM (Entity Framework, NHibernate) to reach this. When you create a new Sensor class, you have to modify the code, but only at the database mapping part.

That table looks like as a table with a [TPH](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) mapping strategy where the SensorType is the discriminator column.

Comment: In the select statment from database it looks like a TPH mapping strategy, but in the underlying database model i intend to implement it as TPT model.

Comment: If i want to use simple method factory pattern i also need some kind of discrimonator column in base table right?

Comment: Yes, you need, but you have the SensorType column, that indicates the type (discriminator).

Comment: In DB schema the base table would look like this (Columns): ID, Code, Name, SensorTypeId (discriminator). right?

Comment: In TPT mapping strategy, you don't really need a discriminator column (for example with ORM), because the table name indicate the concrete type. 
But if you don't use ORM, you maybe need that discriminator column (SensorTypeId) to indicate the type.